# Simplify: $\arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}};$ $0<x<\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\arctan \sqrt{ \frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x} } $$

There are two ways you can procced with this:

**1.**$$=\arctan{\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}}{2\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}}\right)}}$$
$$=\arctan{\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

### $$=\frac{x}{2}$$

**2.** $$=\arctan{\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}-2\cos\frac{x}{2}\sin \frac{x}{2}}{\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}+2\cos{{\frac{x}{2}}}\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}\right)}}$$

$$=\arctan{
\sqrt{
       \left(\frac
                   {\cos \frac{x}{2} -\sin \frac{x}{2} }{\cos \frac{x}{2} +\sin \frac{x}{2} } \right) ^2
}
}$$

$$=\arctan \left(\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\frac{x}{2} + \sin\frac{x}{2}}\right)$$

Dividing by $\cos \frac{x}{2}$

$$=\arctan \left(\frac{1-\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan \frac{x}{2}}\right) $$

$$=\arctan\left[ \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2} \right)\right] $$

### $$=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}$$

So, are both these answers correct? or one of them is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake follows from the following.
$$\sqrt{x^2}\neq x.$$
Take $x=-1.$

Actually,
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$

Answer (score 1):

> **1.**$$=\arctan{\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}}{2\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}}\right)}}$$
>   $$=\arctan{\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

Careful here:

$$\sqrt{\tan^2\tfrac{x}{2}} = \left| \tan\tfrac{x}{2} \right|$$
and you only have $\left| \tan\tfrac{x}{2} \right|=\tan\tfrac{x}{2}$ whenever $\tan\tfrac{x}{2} \ge 0$; while for $\tan\tfrac{x}{2} \le 0$ you would get $\left| \tan\tfrac{x}{2} \right|=-\tan\tfrac{x}{2}$.

This explains the difference and you'll need to know which interval $x$ is in to further simplify; perhaps $\color{blue}{0 <} x < \pi$ was meant instead of only $x<\pi$?